# angular ngx-soap GET request

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, soap

I'm working on Angular 4. I want to get a method in XML from a soap web service and then I want get a function from web service that name is "sayHello", but I can't.

```
        // get wsdl content
        this.http.get('/address/test.wsdl', {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(response => {
        if (response) {
            this.client = this.soap.createClient(response);
            console.log(response);
        }
        });
```

It just return me XML.
I searched a lot but there was no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must give **url** or **path** to wsdl for client constructor, not an XML. Example from docs:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxSoapService, Client, security } from 'ngx-soap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  client: Client;

  constructor(private soap: NgxSoapService) {
    this.soap.createClient('assets/calculator.wsdl').then(client => {
      // if need WSSecurity
      // client.setSecurity(new security.WSSecurity('username', "password", {}));
      this.client = client
    });
  }
}
```